# Spark error when saving to parquet: IndexError: pop from an empty deque

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm getting this error when running a Spark cluster with YARN using AWS EMR service:

```
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1594292341949_0004/container_1594292341949_0004_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1159, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1594292341949_0004/container_1594292341949_0004_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 985, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1594292341949_0004/container_1594292341949_0004_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1164, in send_command
    "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process_ecommerce.py", line 131, in <module>
    cfg["partitions"]["info"]
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1594292341949_0004/container_1594292341949_0004_01_000001/__pyfiles__/spark_utils.py", line 10, in save_dataframe
    .parquet(path)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1594292341949_0004/container_1594292341949_0004_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 844, in parquet
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1594292341949_0004/container_1594292341949_0004_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1594292341949_0004/container_1594292341949_0004_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1594292341949_0004/container_1594292341949_0004_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 336, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o343.parquet
ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:36063)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1594292341949_0004/container_1594292341949_0004_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 929, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque
```

I'm runnig the cluster with 1 master and 20 slave nodes of type r5.2xlarge. Each of them have 8 cpus and 64gb. The configuration of SPARK is:

- 20 gb executor memory
- 30 gb executor memory overhead
- 8 cores per executor
- 1 cpu per task

How can I solve this error?

Comment: What are you doing to trigger the error?

Comment: Nothing, the process work with a sample but fails with this error with the entire dataset.

Comment: @Shadowtrooper: Were you able to resolve this? I have a similar error while writing large files to s3 with Pyspark. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It was a issue with the resoruces of the executor. Try setting more memory to each executor.